# Время удерживания объекта на экране

Tags: java, android, sleep

**Что мне надо?**

Мне нужно выполнить код `showToast("Yes");` после двух секунд удерживания точки на графе нажатой. Желательно, не отпуская точку

**Что я могу?**

Я могу отследить нажатие на точку

```
public void onValueSelected(int lineIndex, int pointIndex, PointValue value) {}
```

Отпускание точки

```
public void onValueDeselected() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Возьмите текущее время new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()) при нажатии и при отпускании и вычтите первое из второго. Вот вам и время удерживания.

Comment: Можно и так, но мне желательно бы выполнить этот код, не отпуская точку. Возможно, вы сталкивались с таким в некоторых приложениях - при удерживании какого-то объекта определенное время телефон немного вибрирует, и мы можем, допустим, переместить объект, удерживая его.

Comment: @MrKlonwar Для достижения этого эффекта вам нужен Drag and Drop. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html